Connecting Jconsole to java app on GCP via SSL ( connect to JMX through JNDI )
I'm trying to make a connection to my java app, using Jconsole. I want to secure that by SSL. At the end I want to move this app to GKE and make the same connection.
What I have:
Simple springboot app, which is printing "hello world" when opened via browser. Literally one controller and empty main class.
starting parameters (VM options):
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1234
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=12345
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
-Djava.rmi.server.host=127.0.0.1

With that, I can open Jconsole, use "remote connection" option and connect to **localhost:1234 **without SSL.
Also, I'm able to use "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1234/jmxrmi" syntax.
It works.
Next step, I want to turn on SSL:
creating keys using this document: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347116/how-to-create-keystore-and-truststore-using-self-signed-certificate
Changing starting parameters to
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1234
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1234
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=cert/server.keystore
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=qweasd
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=cert/server.truststore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=qweasd

Trying to run jConsole using
jconsole -debug -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=client.truststore -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=qweasd localhost:1234
Connection works with syntax "localhost:1234".
Next step, I want to connect with this app locally using "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1234/jmxrmi" syntax.
Getting following error:
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:370)
    at java.management/javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
    at jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:357)
    at jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:313)
    at jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:296)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint]
    at jdk.naming.rmi/com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:138)
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:220)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1839)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1813)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:302)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:252)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:204)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:344)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:116)
    at jdk.naming.rmi/com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:134)
    ... 9 more

Could anyone tell me, what I'm missing?
How the syntax should looks like?
At the end I want to dockerize this app, publish it on GCP and make the same connection, so I assume it should be "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1234/jmxrmi" one.
But want to make it works locally first. Any help?
I've tried:
Adding this options to SSL connection
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
-Djava.rmi.server.host=localhost
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false

Looking at documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/adminguide/radminjmxenablepwdssl.html
Searching at the web, but most of docs that I've found are using "localhost:port" syntax or not using SSL
What I'm expecting:
Use Jconsole to connect with my app working on GKE cluster. It needs SSL.
Edit: I've figured out how to connect to dockerized app hosted on GCP using SSL encryption. I've used host:port syntax, so I think the whole question is not needed anymore. Closing

The title is misleading. The immediate problem is to connect to JMX through JDNI.

@aled shouldn't that be JNDI (rather than JDNI) ?

Yes, sorry it was a phone keyboard typo.
